# AngularJS: Push Checked Checkboxes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to work out how to push checked checkboxes, that are submitted via a form, to an object called `services`, using AngularJS.

These are my objects:

```
$scope.sectors = [ 'health', 'social', 'education' ];

$scope.services = [
      {
        'name': 'Hernia Repair',
        'sectors': { 'health': true }
      },
      {
        'name': 'Cancer',
        'sectors': { 'health': true, 'social': true, 'education': true }
      },
  ];
```

And this is my form:

```
<form role="form" ng-submit="createService(newService)">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="serviceName">Name of Service</label>
    <input id="serviceName" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="newService.name" placeholder="Name of Service">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="serviceName">Another</label>
    <input id="serviceName" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="newService.another" placeholder="Name of Antoher">
  </div>

  <div class="checkbox-inline" ng-repeat="sector in sectors">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="optionsRadios" id="{{sector}}" value="{{sector}}" ng-model="service.sectors[sector]">
      {{sector}}
    </label>
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And here's the JS I'm using to push the data onto the form:

```
function createService(service) {
    $scope.services.push(service);
}

$scope.createService = createService;
```

The `name` seems to get added to the list of `services`, but the `sectors` do not. Can anyone point me in the right direction, or explain what I might be doing wrong.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `newService.sectors[sector]` instead of `service.sectors[sector]` for your ng-models of the radio buttons

Comment: You just have a typo.. Marking for closure.

Comment: @friedi @PSL Changed it to `newService.sectors[sector]`. How can I check that this is being added into `services` correctly??